# Getting a segmentation fault when using initialized local variable to find length of a string

Tags: c

I have to right a program that reads a text file and re-formats it so that a line doesn't have more than a certain amount of characters, set by the user. If a line does exceed the specified character limit, let's say 60 for now, the word that pushes it over the limit gets put on the next line. My problem is that when I use strlen to find the length of a string, which is added to the total character tracker, I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped). I started to mess around with my code and found that when I initialize the variable `maxLine = 60;` I get the segmentation fault, but if were to initialize the variable as `#define MAXLINE 60` I no longer get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("read.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exist\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int length;
    char *string;
    int charCount = 0;
    int maxLine = 60;

    while((fscanf(file, "%s", string)) != EOF)
    {
        length = strlen(string);
        if ((length + charCount) > maxLine)
        {
            charCount = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("%s ", string);
        charCount += length;
        charCount++;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: you're not allocating any space for `string`

Comment: Change `char *string` into something like `char string[1000]`

Comment: You don't seem to be looking for whole words, so as to break the line, at all.

Comment: Allocating space for string fixed the problem. Thank you.